# Como fazer um replicação de um determinada banco no postgres para uma determinada porta?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Bem tenho o seguinte cenário, preciso fazer uma replicação de um banco A para o banco B. Bem até aí consegui fazendo de uma maquina para outra fazendo as seguitntes alterações:

```
Master Machine - 10.0.0.1

    sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
        listen_addresses = 'localhost,10.0.0.1'
        wal_level = hot_standby
        max_replication_slots = 3
        max_wal_senders = 3

    sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf
        host    replication   all        10.0.0.2/32   trust   # the slave

    sudo su - postgres
    psql 
        select * from pg_create_physical_replication_slot('theslave');

    sudo service postgresql restart

Slave Machine 10.0.0.2

   sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
       listen_addresses = 'localhost,10.0.0.2'  
       wal_level = hot_standby
       hot_standby = on
       hot_standby_feedback = on

   sudo service postgresql stop

   sudo su - postgres
       cd ~/9.4
       rm -rf main
       pg_basebackup -v -D main -R -P -h 10.0.0.1

   sudo su postgresql start
```

Bem usando isso aí funciona uma belezinha, porém descobri que os banco que tenho que realizar a replicação não estão na porta 5432 padrão do postgres estão na porta 9700, 9701 e 9702. Ou seja tenho que replicar os dados do bancos de dados que estão na porta 9700,9701 e 9702 no computador master para o computador slave nas respectivas portas 9700, 9701 e 9702.

Qual alteração eu devo fazer?

Comment: No postgresql.conf tem o parâmetro `port` para definir o número da porta do cluster e no pg_basebackup tem o parâmetro `-p` pra definir a porta, acho q alterando esses dois já funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defina os dados para conexão ao servidor *master* no [`recovery.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS-CONFIG) do servidor *slave*. É aqui que você diz pra sua réplica qual é a porta em que ela se conectará:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.0.0.1 port=9700 user=foo password=foopass' 
primary_slot_name = 'theslave'
```

Da mesma forma, ao rodar o [`pg_basebackup`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgbasebackup.html) especifique a porta usando a flag `-p`:

```
pg_basebackup -v -D main -R -P -h 10.0.0.1 -p 9700.
```

E claro, para replicar três *clusters* PostgreSQL que escutam em três portas distintas, você precisa também de três outros servidores *slave*, cada um configurado para replicar de uma porta conforme acima.